# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin AQL download latest artifact matching pattern

Tags: json, maven, jenkins, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm in the process of moving my existing working series of Jenkins Jobs that are chained into a pipeline to the Modern Jenkins As Code Workflow Pipeline.

With this initiative comes various new plugins, that provide steps in which the Pipeline plugin can use. One of those is the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin.

This plugin can accept a json object of Artifactorys "AQL" language, or conversely a very simple pattern to search a series of repos for Artifacts matching a pattern.

I've tried using both the "AQL" and the pattern to resolve my artifacts.

The problem I'm having is, I would like to mimic the behavior of the existing Jenkins Artifact Resolver plugin that can be used in the Jenkins Jobs.

This plugin uses the same patterns I am current providing to the DSL workflow, and only downloads the LATEST, or LAST MODIFIED artifact in that particular return set. I would like to do the same for my new approach.

Here is the result of using a patterned based search:

```
jfrog rt search "client-snapshots/com/client/content_services/search-dist/*.zip"

[Info:] Pinging Artifactory...
    [Info:] Done pinging Artifactory.
    [Info:] Searching Artifactory using AQL query: items.find({"repo": "client-snapshots","$or": [{"$and": [{"path": {"$match":"com/client/content_services/search-dist"},"name":{"$match":"*.zip"}}]},{"$and": [{"path": {"$match":"com/client/content_services/search-dist/*"},"name":{"$match":"*.zip"}}]}]}).include("name","repo","path","actual_md5","actual_sha1","size")
    [Info:] Artifactory response: 200 OK
    [Info:] Found 58 artifacts.
```

Here is the result of using an "AQL" query from a crafted json object

```
jfrog rt search --spec art-search.json
[Info:] Pinging Artifactory...
[Info:] Done pinging Artifactory.
[Info:] Searching Artifactory using AQL query: items.find({"repo":"client-snapshots","$and":[{"$or":[{"path":{"$match":"com/client/content_services"},"name":{"$match":"*search*"}}]},{"$or":[{"path":{"$match":"*dist*"},"name":{"$match":".zip"}}]},{"$or":[{"path":{"$match":"*1.0-SNAPSHOT*"},"name":{"$match":"*"}}]}]}).include("name","repo","path","actual_md5","actual_sha1","size")
[Info:] Artifactory response: 200 OK
[Info:] Found 116 artifacts.
```

And the json for the above query:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "client-snapshots",
          "$and": [
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "com/client/content_services"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$match": "*search*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "*dist*"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$match": ".zip"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "*1.0-SNAPSHOT*"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "$match": "*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "target": "Bazinga/Artifactory/"
    }
  ]
}
```

The first one returns just the zips from the repo I specified, which is what I really want. The json object returns both the poms and the zips from the repo I specified. I could do without the poms, as I'm only interested in downloading zips.

More to my point, I would like to just return the latest zip using one of the above patterns.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found an alternate solution using AQL and PowerShell.

```
$pair = "$($art_user):$($art_pass)"
Write-Verbose "Attempting to convert Artifactory credentials to a base64 string for automation" 
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

Write-Host "Attempting to perform a AQL search."
$aql_search = $art_base_url + "/api/search/aql"
Write-Host "Building aql query with the following parameters, groupID: $group_id, artifactID: $artifact_id, version: $version, classifier: $classifier and repos: $art_generic_repokey."
$aql_query = 'items.find({"repo":"' + $art_generic_repokey + '","$or":[{"$and":[{"path":{"$match":"' + $group_id + '/' + $artifact_id + '/' + $version + '"},"name":{"$match":"' + $artifact_id + '*' + $classifier + '*.' + $extension + '"}}]}]}).sort({"$desc":["modified"]}).limit(1)' 
Write-Host "Built the following aql query: '$aql_query' ."
$aql_content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $aql_search -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $aql_query -ContentType 'text/plain'
Write-Host "Attempting to submit the aql query to the following artifactory server: $art_base_url."
$aql_results = ($aql_content).results
Write-Host "Attempting to parse query results and build the artifact download uri."
$aql_repo,$aql_path,$aql_name = ($aql_results).repo,($aql_results).path,($aql_results).name
$artifactDownloadUri = $art_base_url + '/' + $aql_repo + '/' + $aql_path + '/' + $aql_name 
Write-Host "Found the following uri: $artifactDownloadUri !!"

if ($artifactMimeType  -eq 'application/zip' -or $extension -eq 'zip') {
    Write-Verbose "Attempting to save the artifact to $download_dir/$art_dist_name.zip"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $artifactDownloadUri -Headers $headers -OutFile "$download_dir/$art_dist_name.zip"
}
```